# Should I frame a closet prior to putting in hardwood flooring?

Tags: flooring

Putting hard wood flooring in my office but want to also put in a closet. Should I frame the closet first, or put in the flooring and then frame on top of it?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Walls first, then floor.  Otherwise, if you ever need to remove the floor, you'll be forced to leave some of it in place to hold up your walls (or take the closet out as well).